# Pass object to event function

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'd like to pass object to my event when user clicks on a button.

I tried to pass my object by Reference although it doesn't work.

How can I do?

Thanks

**Code JavaScript**

```
//Object Builder
function Products(name, type)
{
  this.name = name,
  this.type = type
}

//Object
const Product = new Products("CPU", "Hardware");

//I access to button id

const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(Product)
 {
    //It doesn't work
    console.log(Product.name);
 }
)
```

Comment: Just change `function(Product)` to `function()` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: it works, however if my products would are in a function for example called "definedProducts" would it be necessary to pass my function "definedProducts" to my event function like this "function(definedProducts)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are tyring to access the variable `Product` from global scope, there is no need to pass it explicitly. You can directly access that by using `Product` inside the function.

In your case the paramater for the `eventListner` function will be the event by which it got triggered, so even if you write `button.addEventListener("click", function (Product) {})` that `Product` in the parameter will be the event object.

```js
//Object Builder
function Products(name, type) {
    this.name = name,
        this.type = type
}

//Object
const Product = new Products("CPU", "Hardware");

const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log(Product.name);
})
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
```

If you want to pass the `Product` as the argument itself go with below approach.

```js
//Object Builder
function Products(name, type) {
    this.name = name,
        this.type = type
}

//Object
const Product = new Products("CPU", "Hardware");

const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => clickListner(event, Product))

function clickListner (event, Product) {
    console.log(Product.name);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you are trying to pass references of the object to the function when you can directly access the `const` within the function directly like so:

```js
//Object Builder
function Products(name, type)
{
  this.name = name,
  this.type = type
}

//Object
const Product = new Products("CPU", "Hardware");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(Product);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">
click
</button>
```

Comment: You're right I didn't realize about that, altough I appreciate your comment.